# Pod Init Error: "force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)" - at iOS

Tags: ios, init

I encounter this error when I issue a "pod init" command for a project. Terminal is set to "Open Using Rosetta".

Images:

[Open using Rosetta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2qve.png)

[pod init error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srQya.png)

Thanks for helps.

```
(base) airpc@192 InstaClone % pod init

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:228:in `initialize_from_file': [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why do you force the Terminal to run in Rosetta? You're likely to cause problems that way. Apart from that, this looks like CocoaPods bug so you first try to update CocoaPods, and if the error persists, report it to them.

Comment: Hi, my macbook has M1 CPU. That's why the rosetta option is selected.

Comment: That's not a valid reason, my Mac is also running on M1. CocoaPods runs just fine on M1.

Comment: I get the error regardless of shell architecture. Is there a solution?

Comment: This error also occurs on an Intel Mac using a newly cretated project on Xcode 14.

Comment: @DielsonSales You are right, I have same error on my newly created project on intel based Mac.
Did any one found any solution?

Comment: This helped me => sudo gem update xcodeproj

Answer (score 208, accepted):

I found that there may be a problem with the newly created project in Xcode14。

You can temporarily solve this problem by following the steps in the picture.

[image]

Comment: You typically can't open a project in Xcode when you're compiling with this error.

Comment: The only thing it does is to change the string of `compatibilityVersion` to `"Xcode 13.0"` and `objectVersion` to 55.

Comment: This worked like a magic after my 4 hours efforts
Thanks

Answer (score 47):

Try `sudo gem update xcodeproj` or `sudo gem update` for all gems. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Update CocoaPods:**
Outdated versions of CocoaPods may have bugs and compatibility issues. Run the following command to update CocoaPods to the latest version:

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```

**Clear CocoaPods Cache**
Sometimes, clearing the CocoaPods cache can resolve issues. Run the following command to clear the CocoaPods cache:

```
pod cache clean --all
```

Comment: was any generative AI involved in any way in the writing of this answer?

Comment: @starball no not involved

Answer (score 0):

I just modify this text to the old value, and then it is ok:

[image]